# php codeigniter MySQL search query

Tags: mysql, search

I want to create a search query on MySQL database that will consist of 5 different strings typed in from user. I want to query 5 different table columns with these strings.

When I for example have input fields like:

first name, last name, address, post number, city.

How should I query the database that I dont always get all the rows.

My query is something like this:

```
SELECT user_id, username
from users
where
a like %?% AND
b like %?% AND
c like %?% AND
d like %?% AND
e like %?%;
```

When I exchange the AND for OR I always get all the results which makes sense, and when I use AND I get only the exact matches...

Is there any function or statement that would help me with this?

**EDIT**

The code I use is:

```
$sql = "select users.user_id, first_name
    from users
    inner join user_normal_aos
    on users.user_id = user_normal_aos.user_id
    inner join normal_areas_of_expertise
    on user_normal_aos.normal_areas_of_expertise_id = normal_areas_of_expertise.normal_areas_of_expertise_id
    where 
    users.first_name like ? AND
    users.kanzlei like ? AND
    normal_areas_of_expertise.normal_aoe like ? AND
    users.postcode like ? AND
    users.city like ?";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql,
        array(
            '%'.$lawyer_name.'%',
            '%'.$kanzlei.'%',
            '%'.$area_of_expertise.'%',
            '%'.$post_code.'%',
            '%'.$city.'%')
        );
```

Comment: Could you first define "search query"? What do you like to achieve?

Comment: What exactly you want man ?

Comment: did you tried to replace the ?, manually, for your search criteria?

Comment: I want that I will get only the information that user requires according to his input parameters. For example if the user wants every lawyer whose name is John and also he lives in London... But creating such query for every possibility sounds like I am doing something wrong ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example use PHP to adjust your query based on what fields you have entered.

```
$where = array();
$replacements = array();
/* you can also compare if string is not null or not empty...
   this is just example using isset */
if (isset($lawyer_name)) {
    $where[] = 'users.first_name like ?';
    $replacements[] = '%'.$lawyer_name.'%';
}

/* repeat this if again for all your fields .... */

$sql = "..... where ".implode(' AND ', $where);

$query = $this->db->query($sql,
    $replacements
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `!== ""` instead of `isset()` .. the isset() method didn't work or sth.